# What is the step-by-step way to do the integral of $\int \tan^4 u \sec^3 u \,du$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int \tan^4 u~ \sec^3 u\, du$$

The 2006 MIT OpenCourseWare notes ["Single Variable Calculus" (PDF link via mit.edu)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec26.pdf) arrives at this integral (with a multiplied constant) in Example 2, but it did not show the complete way to solve it. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20tan%5E4%20x%20sec%5E3%20x%20dx) knows the answer, but it is not free to use.

The lecture note link actually provided some context about a family of integrals: $\int \sec^n x\tan^m x dx$. However, the lecture note only solved two cases: 1st, when $n$ is even; 2nd, when $m$ is odd. The integral does not belong to either case.

I tried leveraging the following results, but failed to get the solution.

$\sec^2 x = 1 + \tan^2 x$

$\int \sec^2 x  dx = \tan x + c$

$\int \sec x \tan x dx = \sec x + c$

$\int \tan x dx = -\log(\cos x) + c$

$\int \sec x dx = \log (\tan x + \sec x) + c$

Comment: say $\tan(u) = t.$ Then see what happens.

Comment: Your question has votes to close for "missing context". I think providing links to the OpenCourseWare notes is good, but it would be helpful if you explained what the notes *did* show (e.g. reproduce some of their working). This would make the question self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start writing
$$I=\int\tan^4\left(u\right)\sec^3\left(u\right)\,du=\int\sec^3\left(u\right)\left(\tan^2\left(u\right)\right)^2\,du$$
$$I=\int\sec^3\left(u\right)\left(\sec^2\left(u\right)-1\right)^2\,du=\int\left(\sec^7\left(u\right)-2\sec^5\left(u\right)+\sec^3\left(u\right)\right)\mathrm{d}u$$ Now, use the reduction formula

$$\int\sec^n\left(u\right)\,du=\frac{n-2}{n-1}\,\int\sec^{n-2}\left(u\right)\,du+\frac 1 {n-1}\sec^{n-2}\left(u\right)\,\tan(u)$$ starting with
$$\int\sec\left(u\right)\,du=\log\left(\tan\left(u\right)+\sec\left(u\right)\right)$$

Comment: In my opinion, your solution is correct. The recursive formula is the key. We need to do the followings: $\int sec^n x dx = \int sec^{(n - 2)} x (tan x)' dx$ and then use integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

*Bioche's rules* suggest to use the substitution
$$s=\sin u,\quad \mathrm ds=\cos u\,\mathrm du$$
so you obtain the integral of a rational function of $s$:
$$\int \tan^4 u  \sec^3 u\,\mathrm du=\int\frac{\sin^4u\,\mathrm du}{\cos^7u}= \int\frac{s^4\,\mathrm ds}{\cos^8u}=\int\frac{s^4\,\mathrm ds}{(1-s^2)^4},$$
which you can determine using partial fractions.